# REST Add List Item of Custom Content Type

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, rest, ajax

In my SharePoint add-in, I have already utilized the REST call for creating a new list item:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Example List')/items",
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; odata=verbose",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "contentType": "application/json; odata=verbose",
    },
    data : JSON.stringify({
        __metadata: {"type": "SP.Data.Example_x0020_ListListItem"},
        Title: "_",
        field1: "val1",
        field2: "val2",
        field3: "val3"
    })
})
```

My question is, how do I add a list item of a custom content type?  What exactly do I put as the value for the "type" key in the __metadata object?
I was thinking it would be something like

```
__metadata: {"type": "SP.Data.MyContentTypeName"},
```

but that doesn't seem to work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Any help from my answer?

Comment: Not Yet, now when I use the exact same request, with the ContentTypeId key/value added, it is throwing an error with the message "To add an item to a document library, use SPFileCollection.Add()"

Comment: It works for lists. I have tested. In document library, you can not try this way. At first, you need to upload a file and thereafter you can modify the metadata. AFAIK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to deal with `__metadata`. Just specify your `ContentTypeId` in your request body and that's all.

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    __metadata: {
        "type": "SP.Data.Example_x0020_ListListItem"
    },
    Title: "_",
    field1: "val1",
    field2: "val2",
    field3: "val3",
    ContentTypeId: "Your content type id"
})
```

In the `__metadata` you need to specify `ListItemEntityTypeFullName` and it is same for all content types.