# SP Online REST API Durable Document Link

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, api

My google searches have all led to dead ends.

Is there a way to retrieve the `durable link` code for a document using the REST API?

When you copy a link in the GUI, it takes the form of:-

```
https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/mylibrary/myDocSet?d=w9570bf1d91a541679abbf03996bbbff7
```

I would like to know how to retrieve the `d=....` part, using the SharePoint REST API, given I have the ID of the library item (e.g `847`) and the library location details etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is present in the `LinkingUrl` property of the file in a document library.

So, to get that value, you need to modify the endpoint as below:

```
https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('mylibrary')/items(847)
?$select=File/LinkingUrl&$expand=File
```

Reference - [SP Durable links](https://blog.portiva.nl/2015/09/14/sp2016-durable-links/)

Comment: I had seen that page, however I couldn't resolve how to apply it to an endpoint.

Comment: I get a response from the server, however it does not appear to contain the required field. (It does not contain a value that matches the string obtainable from the SP GUI for the same Document Set in the same Document Library) Nor does it contain a node 'LinkingURL'. Any other hints to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: The above code works for Files. To make it work for folder or document sets, you can use `https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('mylibrary')/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items(32)?$select=*,Folder/UniqueId&$expand=Folder`. It will give you the uniqueId property of the document set which will be the value you can use for `d=...` section !

Comment: That's great - thank you. The REST API is now returning a `<d:UniqueId>` node, with a value _similar_ to the GUI's. Is it safe to assume that I should always pre-pend a `w`, and strip out the dashes (`-`)  to arrive at the same link the GUI would supply?

Comment: Also, BTW, I believe there was a surplus `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')` in the URI you posted in your comment, above - I ended up using `https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('mylibrary')/items(32)?$select=*,Folder/UniqueId&$expand=Folder`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what is used ! In case of file, we get full url which is convenient. For folders will have to work with unique Id

Comment: Thanks for your help! Any chance you have any light to shed on my other current problem? [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/248294/sp-online-rest-api-change-the-content-type-of-a-document-library-item)